# Improving Prolog Program with Red Cuts

Tags: prolog

I wrote a Prolog program that calculates the price of a hotel room based on season and type of room. Can this program be improved by using red cuts?

```
season(Month, Season) :- member(Month, [may,sep]), Season = low.
season(Month, Season) :- member(Month, [jul,aug]), Season = high.
season(Month, Season) :- Month = jun, Season = mid.

room_price(basic, 80).
room_price(deluxe, 100).
room_price(superior, 120).

room_price(Type, Month, Price) :-
    season(Month, low),
    room_price(Type, BasicPrice),
    Price is BasicPrice * 0.8, !.

room_price(Type, Month, Price) :-
    season(Month, high),
    room_price(Type, BasicPrice),
    Price is BasicPrice * 1.2, !.

room_price(Type, Month, Price) :-
    season(Month, mid),
    room_price(Type, Price).
```

Comment: This program can be improved without using any cut!

Comment: How do you make them red? do you use syntax highlighting in your editor or maybe some CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an auxiliary predicate with the season as the first argument, taking advantage of Prolog first-argument indexing:

```
room_price(Type, Month, Price) :-
    season(Month, Season),
    room_price(Season, Type, Month, Price).

room_price(low, Type, Month, Price) :-
    room_price(Type, BasicPrice),
    Price is BasicPrice * 0.8.

room_price(high, Type, Month, Price) :-
    room_price(Type, BasicPrice),
    Price is BasicPrice * 1.2.

room_price(mid, Type, Month, Price) :-
    room_price(Type, Price).
```

Answer (score 4):

As a hint (because this feels like homework), map them like with SQL database normalization:

```
month_season(may, low).
month_season(jun, mid).
month_season(jul, high).
month_season(aug, high).
month_season(sep, low).

season_mult(low, 80).
season_mult(mid, 100).
season_mult(high, 120).

type_mult(basic, 80).
type_mult(deluxe, 100).
type_mult(superior, 120).
```

An (advanced-level) alternative is https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=term_expansion/2

Answer (score 4):

I'd refactor things like this:

https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/FbqeSUnP.pl

just 4 lines of actual code and some facts.

```
room_price( T , M , P ) :-    % compute the room rate for room type and a month...
    season(M,S),              % - bucket the month into a season (S)
    seasonal_adjustment(S,F), % - determine the seasonal rate adjustment factor
    base_rate(T,B),           % - get the base rate for the specified room type
    P is B * F                % - compute the room rate
    .                         % Easy!

season( jan , low  ) .
season( feb , low  ) .
season( mar , low  ) .
season( apr , low  ) .
season( may , low  ) .
season( jun , mid  ) .
season( jul , high ) .
season( aug , high ) .
season( sep , low  ) .
season( oct , low  ) .
season( nov , low  ) .
season( dec , low  ) .

base_rate( basic    ,   80 ) .
base_rate( deluxe   ,  100 ) .
base_rate( superior ,  120 ) .

seasonal_adjustment( low  , 0.8 ) .
seasonal_adjustment( mid  , 1.0 ) .
seasonal_adjustment( high , 1.2 ) .
```